# SSH Putty Port Forward Over Specific Interface

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

```
Server1: 201.23.253.12 and 192.168.1.12
Server2: 192. 168.2.76
Server3: 201.23.253.25 and 192.168.1.25
```

I have servers that I access remotely via SSH. Server1 is a jump server that has a internal and an external IP address. Server2 is a web server that only has an internal IP addresss.

I'm trying to access a web service running on Server2.

I can connect to Server1 and from Server 1 connect to Server2. **Server2 is only accessible from Server1 via the internal interface.** I need to use.

```
ssh -b 192,168.1.12 root@192.168.2.76
```

Right now I can port forward from Server1 to Server3 directly from my local machine using Putty:

```
ssh -L 443:201.33.253.25:443 201.23.253.12
```

**How do I forward port 443 on Server2?**

Comment: Does `ssh -L 443:192.168.1.76:443 root@201.23.253.12` not work?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that Server2 is on a different internal network.

Comment: ssh -f -N -C -L443:192. 168.2.76:443 root@201.23.253.12